# Why doesn't this graph have a maximum value by the Extreme Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus

I was provided this graph and asked if it passed the Extreme Value Theorem. I thought yes. I can see that this function is discontinuous...however, I was informed that this graph actually fails the Extreme Value Theorem due to the hole at x = 2. This caught me off guard, because I thought for certain there was a maximum.

[image: Picture of Graph that Fails EVT]

Is the reason that there is no maximum for this graph because if someone were to say, "Well, the max is clearly 7.999"...another person could say, "Actually it's 7.9999"...and then another person could say...etc?

Comment: You've got the right idea.  $8$ is the least upper bound for the values of $f(x)$, but $f(x)$ never actually attains the value $8$, although it does attain values arbitrarily close to (but less than) $8$.

Comment: The Extreme Value Theorem does not apply because the function is not continuous on $[1,3]$. So invoking the EVT (as you do in your subject) is a red herring. It’s not invited to this party.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “passes the Extreme Value Theorem.” If you mean, “does it satisfy the hypothesis?” then the answer is no. If you mean “does it satisfy the conclusion?” then the answer is again no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum and minimum of a set are elements of the set. In your case the maximum is not attained and as you have explained any number close to $2$  is not a maximum.

That is why we have the notion of supremum of a set which is the least upper bound of the set and it does not have to belong to the set.

We say that $2$ is the supremum of the values of this function not a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

All the hypotheses of the EVT are not satisfied; in this case, your function is not continuous over the closed interval $[1,3]$.

Comment: Suggestion: “all the hypthesis of the EVT are not satisfied” seems to say that each and every assumption of the EVT is not satisfied; so that the domain is not finite and closed, the function is not continuous. You mean “Not all the hypothesis of the EVT are satisfied.” English is not commutative!